# What is a convenient way to store and retrieve boolean values in a CSV file

Tags: python, csv

If I store a boolean value using the CSV module, it gets converted to the strings `True` or `False` by the `str()` function. However, when I load those values, a string of `False` evaluates to being `True` because it's a non-empty string.

I can work around it by manually checking the string at read time with an IF statement to see what the string is, but it's somewhat less than  elegant. Any better ideas, or is this just one of those things in the programming world?

Comment: "One of those things"?  One of *what* things?

Comment: At lower level, Python would be simply doing that IF statement you are talking about!

Comment: @S.Lott: Annoying things. @fjsj: True but I'd like to hide the IF from view. I think i've found a convenient way to do this but wondered if anyone else had hit this issue.

Answer (score 9):

### Ways to store boolean values in CSV files

- Strings: Two common choices are`true` and `false`, `True` and `False`, but I've also seen `yes` and `no`.
- Integers: `0` or `1`
- Floats: `0.0` or `1.0`

Let's compare the respective advantages / disadvantages:

- Strings:

  - `+` A human can read it
  - `-` CSV readers will have it as a string and both will evaluate to "true" when `bool` is applied to it
- Integers:

  - `+` CSV readers might see that this column is integer and `bool(0)` evaluates to false.
  - `+` A bit more space efficient
  - `-` Not totally clear that it is boolean
- Floats:

  - `+` CSV readers might see that this column is integer and `bool(0.0)` evaluates to false.
  - `-` Not totally clear that it is boolean
  - `+` Possible to have null (as NaN)

The Pandas CSV reader shows the described behaviour.

### Convert Bool strings to Bool values

Have a look at [`mpu.string.str2bool`](https://mpu.readthedocs.io/en/latest/string.html#mpu.string.str2bool):

```
>>> str2bool('True')
True
>>> str2bool('1')
True
>>> str2bool('0')
False
```

which has the following implementation:

```
def str2bool(string_, default='raise'):
    """
    Convert a string to a bool.

    Parameters
    ----------
    string_ : str
    default : {'raise', False}
        Default behaviour if none of the "true" strings is detected.

    Returns
    -------
    boolean : bool

    Examples
    --------
    >>> str2bool('True')
    True
    >>> str2bool('1')
    True
    >>> str2bool('0')
    False
    """
    true = ['true', 't', '1', 'y', 'yes', 'enabled', 'enable', 'on']
    false = ['false', 'f', '0', 'n', 'no', 'disabled', 'disable', 'off']
    if string_.lower() in true:
        return True
    elif string_.lower() in false or (not default):
        return False
    else:
        raise ValueError('The value \'{}\' cannot be mapped to boolean.'
                         .format(string_))
```

Answer (score 3):

There's almost always a simpler (and often more convenient) way, and most of the time it is already included in Python's amazing standard library.

In this case you can just use `True` and `False`, then parse them with `ast`'s `literal_eval` method.

Let's say we have a file called `test.csv` with the following content:

```
nonetype,integer,boolean
None,123,False
```

We also have a `test.py` script to parse the file:

```py
import ast
import csv

with open('test.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:
        nonetype = ast.literal_eval(row['nonetype'])
        integer = ast.literal_eval(row['integer'])
        boolean = ast.literal_eval(row['boolean'])
        print(type(nonetype), type(integer), type(boolean))
```

When we run the script we can see that the values get parsed as expected.

```
$ python3 test.py
<class 'NoneType'> <class 'int'> <class 'bool'>
```

This method is also safe to use, even with input from untrusted sources, more info [on the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html?highlight=ast#ast.literal_eval).

Answer (score 0):

use the int() function to covert the boolean to their int values and then store those.  that being said, eli-bendersky's comment above is worth noting.

Comment: I considered that, but the value stored in the CSV file needs to be easily parseable by the human eye. If I was just storing it for machine processing I wouldn't be using a CSV file and Eli's comment would be spot on.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if answering your own question is bad form or not, but here's the solution I've come up with. It basicaly consists of hiving off that pesky IF statement I was talking about into a function.

```
def setyesNo(value):
    if value: return 'Yes'
    else: return 'No'

def checkYesNo(text):
    if text == 'Yes': return True
    else: return False
```

Then in my dictWriter do this.

```
for item in mylist:
    writer.writerow( {'Is Cool' : setYesNo(item.is_cool),
                      .....
                      })
```

And in dictReader.

```
for line in reader:
    item MyObject(is_Cool=checkYesNo(line['Is Cool']),
                  .....
                  )
    mylist.append(item)
```