# How to store bool variable outside of python and read it back in?

Tags: python, boolean

I need a little help with python.

I have written a small program and would now like to store a bool value outside the program, so that a certain action in the program is only executed if the bool was `True` or `False`.

It is important that the value is retained even if the program is not running. In addition, the bool must be able to be set when the program is running.

I am grateful for any help.

I hope I get an idea now on how exactly this can be done.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any config file to store the bool value( you can use normal files too but it depends on context). I doesn't take you long to find a good library to manage config file of any type in python.

You can also use env to store the bool value but i don't recommend it.

Answer (score 0):

### You can import another python file with the bool

- Create another python file (I'll call it **myboolscript.py** for now)
- Add your bool to **myboolscript.py**: `myboolvar = True`
- Add the import in you main script: `from myboolscript import myboolvar`
- Now you can use it anywhere as a variable

---

**Example:**

*main.py*

```
from myboolscript import myboolvar

print("Hello World!")

if myboolvar == True:
  print("Bool is True")
```

*myboolscript.py*

```
myboolvar = True
```

**Output:**

```
Hello World!
Bool is True
```

---

### You can also use CSV files

It is worth noting that using a python script may be easy, but isn't very efficient. There are plenty of other ways to do it, like using a CSV file.

Here's a post on it:
[What is a convenient way to store and retrieve boolean values in a CSV file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3717785/what-is-a-convenient-way-to-store-and-retrieve-boolean-values-in-a-csv-file)